# How to find the cpython source code file for a specific 3rd party (NumPy for instance) API?

Tags: python, numpy, cpython

This question comes from this [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/54413/74719).

I am digging out the underlying logic for `numpy.linalg.eig`.

```
w, v = np.linalg.eig(C.T*C)
v
matrix([[-0.9486833 , -0.31622777],
        [ 0.31622777, -0.9486833 ]])
```

the implementation of np.linalg.eig

```
w, vt = _umath_linalg.eig(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
```

is linked [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.1/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L1311), which links to `_umath_linalg.py`

_umath_linalg.py corresponds to `<python3.6>/site-packages/numpy/linalg/_umath_linalg.cpython-36m-darwin.so`

I searched lots of keywords comes from _umath_linalg.eig on the cpython source code [gh repo](https://github.com/python/cpython#installing-multiple-versions) and got nothing related.

in this case, how to find the cpython source code file for _umath_linalg.cpython-36m-darwin.so or `_umath_linalg.eig`?

Comment: Numpy isn't part of CPython. It might have the name in its name (however you should best express that) but the code will be in numpy, not CPython

Comment: Go up a level in the github repository, and see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.1/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src.  From there you'll see lots of references to `lapack`.  Tracing `numpy` source code is not an easy task.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly where the different libraries live outside of PyPi isn't a common location across all modules, but usually they're somewhere on github. In this case you're not looking for the source of cpython itself, but of the linalg module inside numpy. Asking a search engine for `numpy linalg github` will [give you the location](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/linalg.py).

You can also [use `pip download`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/) to download the source code of any module available on PyPi to a directory of your choice. This can be useful for fetching a specific version and to see what has been uploaded to PyPi:

```
pip download numpy -d <directory>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. the link in `Asking a search engine for numpy linalg github will give you the location` had been provided in my question, which is not what I am asking for. I am asking for the **cpython** source code rather than python source code. I've run the `pip download` command and got a whl file, which is usually used to install a package. do you mean I can find the **cpython** source code in the whl file? if yes. How can I do that?

Comment: A `.whl` file is just an archive that contains multiple other files as a single dependency. There is nothing special regarding cpython inside that file. You can use `wheel unpack` to extract the contents of the file itself. The `.so` file is usually just the python code compiled to an installed module on installation - `download` will give you the source, which you can build yourself with `--build` as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply, `wheel unpack` gives a `numpy` directory, which seems to be a tiny version of gh source or my local numpy package. what is related to `_umath_linalg.eig` in "umpy/linalg" directory is "linalg.py", which had been already provided in my post. I cannot find anything related to the underlying implementation of `_umath_linalg.eig`. any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that file lives together with the linalg.py file in the same directory. [umath_linalg.c.src](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src)