# In the context of python and cpython, is a ".c.src" file a c source code file? how to compile this kind of file?

Tags: python, numpy, cpython

this question comes from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56781686/10731613).

digging `numpy.linalg.eig` leads to a [umath_linalg.c.src](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.1/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src) file.

in the context of python and cpython, is a ".c.src" file a c source code file? how to compile this `umath_linalg.c.src` file?

Comment: `numpy` `src` files are not directly compileable. `numpy` setup does some sort of preprocessing.  I don't know what you are trying to do, but re-using or modifying these files will require a significant amount of study.

Comment: Not quite. As you can see, they contain `@something@` tokens which aren't valid C. So, it's probably a template which requires some preprocessing (and then turns into a genuine C file after it).